# Getting JSON data from Twitter using ID in PHP

Tags: php, twitter

I have a following script which helps me getting data in json format from a particular Facebook ID.

Here's the code

```
if($recipy_info[0]['social_media']=='facebook')
    {
    $pageContent = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$recipy_info[0]['post_userid'].'?fields=id,name,picture,birthday');
    $parsedJson  = json_decode($pageContent);
    //$facebook_info= https://graph.facebook.com/100003384367738?fields=id,name,picture,birthday
    }
```

Now the issue is that I want to have a similar work for Twitter, I don't have screen name, all I have is just the id `1897279429`.

I have a url `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/1897279429.json`, but it gives me this error:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}
```

How can I sort my problem?

I want to get JSON data from the id I have.

Answer (score 0):

Since API 1.1 you are required to authenticate first before you can get the public tweets from a user. Please take a look at the API documentation here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs